# python case sensitive disable and get eual string

Tags: python-3.x

```
def worker(queue):
    while True:
        if not queue.empty():
            words = 'BananA'
            words1 = 'nut'
            words2 = 'KreMA'
            words3 = 'KIVI'
            words4 = 'TesT'
            process(data, words, words1, words2, words3, words4)

def process(data, words, words1, words2, words3, words4):
    if (search != words):
        print("Words Not Found")
    if (words in search or words1 in search or words2 in search or words3 in search or words4 in search):
        print("Words Found  : " + str(Words) + "\n")
        file = open("finded.txt","a")
        file.write("Words Founds "+ str(words)
        file.close()
```

but, if change the line if "banana"  to "Banana"

the code not work, I need Banana or BANANA or BaNaNa get equal, and get true,

Comment: or, string = "BANANA" or "Banana" or BanANA" all item get equal and print yes

Answer (score 1):

You may for example compare always lower case:

```
fruits = ["apple", "baNana", "cherry"]

if "banana".lower() in map(str.lower, fruits):
   print("yes")

if "BaNanA".lower() in map(str.lower, fruits):
   print("yes2")
```

output:

```
yes
yes2
```

#### EDIT:

After you edited code:

1) 
This code `if (search != words):` followed by `words in search` and preceded by `words = 'BananA'` looks like have no possibility to work - looks mutually conflicting.

2) 
Assuming that this yours code `if (words in search or words1 in search or words2 in search or words3 in search or words4 in search):` is what you want to do. Try such way:

```
if (words.lower() in map(str.lower, search) or words1.lower() in map(str.lower, search) or words2.lower() in map(str.lower, search) or words3.lower() in map(str.lower, search) or words4.lower() in map(str.lower, search)):
```

or same but written **much** better:

```
search = list(map(str.lower, search))
for w in [words, words1, words2, words3, words4]:
    if w.lower() in search:
        ...
```

Please note that in the second case `map` is enclosed by `list`. This is because map result is an iterator. And without this, you can *use it* only once.

Comment: oh thanks for answer, but, ı write a dictionary script, and user example input banaNa, no result, because banane is in tx files, written a BANANA, and I cannt correct all word, ı dont know which word a capitalize or non capitalize, I need, banana BananA BanaNA or BANANA or BaNANA get equal, and find all, one string.

Comment: Please give an example, because this example match all combinations that you mention. No matter what user input f.e. `BaNana` and what is in source f.e. `bANAna`.

Comment: words1 = 'Banana'
            words2 = 'domato'
            words3 = 'appLe'
            words4 = 'chewY'
            words5 = 'NuT'
            
   if (words != search):
        print("{:<34}".format(str(word)) + " " not found in dictionary"))
    if (words in search or words1 in search or words2 in search or words3 in search or words4 in search):
        print("words found")
        
        if change the words1 BANANA not found :(

Comment: Share your exactly code, please. 
I do not see you using proposed changing case in above code.

Comment: Adam Thanks for all, I change the code main question, because comment is small for enter full code.